# 2D array in C with variable 2nd dimension

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to define an 2D array in C with variable (but fixed) 2nd dimension?
So what I want is more or less something like

```
    int array[3][] = {{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}}
```

what does not work. Is there any way to get there
where the length of `array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2`  and `array[2]=3`?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "variable (but fixed)"? Do you mean you want each row to be a different length, as suggested by your initializer?

Comment: with variable but fixed i meant, each row may have a different length (variable) but i know in advance the size it should have ("but fixed"). sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to define an 2D array in C with variable (but fixed) 2nd dimension? So what I want is more or less something like
>
> ```
> int array[3][] = {{1},{1,2},{1,2,3}}
> ```
>
> [...] Is there any way to get there where the length of array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2 and array[2]=3?

No, there isn't.

C arrays are sequences of elements of the same type.  The number and type of the elements are attributes of each array *type*, not of the array objects having that type.  C array indexing depends fundamentally on that.

C 2D arrays are arrays where the element type is a specific array type (with, therefore, a specific number of elements).  Thus,

```
int array[3][2];
```

declares `array` to be an array of three elements, each one an array of two `int`s.

What you can do is have an array of *pointers* to arrays of various lengths.  For example:

```
int el0[] = { 1 };
int el1[] = { 1, 2 };
int el2[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int *array[] = { el0, el1, el2 };
```

In some important respects, you can handle such an array much the same way that you do a *bona fide* 2D array.  Note, however, that that requires either assumptions or separate bookkeeping about the lengths of the pointed-to arrays, and that the three 1D arrays are not necessarily contiguous in memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use compound literals. However if the dimensions of the internal arrays are not increased sequentially you have to store the dimensions in some other array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int *a[] = 
    {
        ( int[] ){ 1 }, ( int [] ){ 1, 2 }, ( int [] ){ 1, 2, 3 }
    };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ); i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
1 
1 2 
1 2 3
```

That is you have an array of pointers each of which points to the first element of unnamed arrays of the appropriate dimensions.
In this example the unnamed arrays have the same automatic storage duration as the array of pointers.

Comment: thanks vlad, that is actually what john is explaining in the answer i accepted. sry for not choosing yours but johns explanation lights it up more accessible what might help others as well

Answer (score 1):

Yo can store your data in a linearized array. The size of the array grows by the row of triangular numbers ( **0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55** ... ).
If you have an index `[x][y]` you can calculae the index in the linearized triangular array by the formula `[ y*(y+1)/2 + x ]`, in which `x` has to be less or equal `y`.

```
int main(void)
{
    int rows = 10;
    int size = rows*(rows+1)/2; // size of linearized array
    int *triangularArray = malloc( sizeof( int ) * size );

    for ( int y = 0; y < rows; y ++ )
    {
        for ( int x = 0; x <= y; x ++ )
        {
            int index = y*(y+1)/2 + x; // linearized index for [x][y] ( x <= y )
            triangularArray[ index ] = x+1;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i ++ )
    {
        if ( i > 0 && triangularArray[i] <= triangularArray[i-1] )
            printf( "\n" );
        printf( "%3d", triangularArray[i] );
    }

    free( triangularArray );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will you know ahead of time what the second array's size will be?

You should be able to define a function that takes in the second array's size as input to initialize it with

```
array buildArr(int size) {

    int[][] newArr = new int [whatever][size]();

    return newArr;

}
```

Comment: That is C++, not C.

Comment: no that would leave me an array which has length size in the 2nd dimension, but i want to have the length of the 2nd dimension to be variable (but fixed)

Comment: @ryyker, he seems to mean that he wants each (1D array) element of the 2D array to have its own, independent, fixed length.